# React App cannot retrieve data from MongoDB after build

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, firebase-hosting

My App sends some Ordering List to the Backend on MongoDb, after i build the app, it couldn't get the list in the database anymore.

my server.js looks like this

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
require("colors");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/.env" });

connectDB();

// Routes
const orderings = require("./routes/orders");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.use("/api/v1/orderings", orderings);

//This code below should be solving the issue, but i don't understand why

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"))
  );
}

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on PORT:${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
);
```

and in my client folder in the package.json file:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:9000",
```

A Method in my Context that gets the Orders

```
const getOrders = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/v1/orderings");
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_ORDERS",
        payload: response.data.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "ORDER_ERROR",
        payload: error.response.data.error,
      });
    }
  };
```

Bring it in a component

```
const { orders, getOrders } = useContext(OrderContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

it works in development mode i have `5 Arrays of the Orders,` but in production it says `[]`

I deployed to firebase and then in the `console`, still empty `Array []`

```
https://react-mouka.web.app/
```

Comment: Can you make console.log(response) in getOrders() ?

Comment: it returns undefined